# Show that the discrete metric can not be obtained from $X\neq\{0\}$

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

If $X \neq \{ 0\}$ is a vector space. How does one go about showing that the discrete metric on $X$ cannot be obtained from any norm on $X$?

I know this is because $0$ does not lie in $X$, but I am having problems. Formalizing a proof for this.

This is also my final question for some time, after this I will reread the answers, and not stop until I can finally understand these strange spaces.

Comment: The hypothesis that $X\ne\{0\}$ doesn’t mean that $0$ is not in $X$: it means that $X$ is not the trivial one-point vector space.

Comment: Except if $X=\mathbb F_2$ the vector space over the field $\mathbb F_2$ with two elements.

Comment: Related: [Topological vector space with discrete topology is the zero space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492483).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that the discrete metric only takes values of $1$ and $0$. Now suppose it comes from some norm $||.||$.  Then for any $\alpha$ in the underlying field of your vector space and $x,y \in X$, you must have that

$$\lVert\alpha(x-y)\rVert = \lvert\alpha\rvert\,\lVert x-y\rVert.$$

But now $||x-y||$ is a fixed number and I can make $\alpha$ arbitrarily large and consequently the discrete metric does not come from any norm on $X$.

Comment: I guessed you meant $|\alpha|$ rather than $\alpha$. I also played around a bit with your $\LaTeX$ in the hope of making that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Suppose that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ generates the discrete topology on $X$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\{x\in X:\|x\|<\epsilon\}=\{0\}$. By hypothesis $X$ contains at least one non-zero vector $y$. Let $\alpha=\|y\|>0$. Where is the vector $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}y$?

Comment: Hmm. You are using discrete topology where the question asker said discrete metric, but I won't downvote because I think this is interesting itself.

Comment: @Ben: I’m a bit bemused that anyone would even consider downvoting on that basis: The discrete metric generates the discrete topology, so showing that the latter is not generated by a norm is a perfectly reasonable way to show that the former isn’t (and more besides).

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. I had assumed that you had answered a genuinely different question. (Still, the same question for the discrete metric is more obvious in my view, cf. the other answer)

Comment: @Ben: What’s obvious depends so much on one’s background. A functional analyst would probably agree with you; I’m a set-theoretic topologist, so it’s not really surprising that I find the topological solution much more obvious.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:$\dfrac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}y$ will be in $\{x\in X:\|x\|<\epsilon\}=\{0\}$,Which is an absurd equation...

Comment: I have one small question: Is the statement in OP true in case of X over **any field**? If the field is R or C, then clearly for any non zero x, we have $d(x,0)=1$ and ||2x||=2||x||=2= d(2x,0)=1, a contradiction. But if the field is not R or C, then how can one say that $\frac {\epsilon}{2\alpha}$ is a scalar?

Comment: @Koro: the vectors spaces studied in functional analysis are over the real or the complex fields.

Comment: @Koro: To define norms and in general the concept of topological vector space over arbitrary field you need to define a valuation (absolute value or modulus) on a field. The definition of norm is similar to the one in complex (real) normed spaces. Things may  not very be well behaved however, specially for finite fields. If you are interest in that, here is areference: C.Perez-Garcia, W.H.Schikhof, *Locally Convex Spaces over non-Arquimedean Valued Fields*,   Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics (2010).

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Thanks for the help; I would not have been able to offer a reference.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Thanks a lot :-).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose$(X,d)$ is a vector space with the discrete metric.
If$X$ is a normed space, then for ∀ $x≠y ∈ X$,$α≠0 ∈K, αx≠αy$.So then $\lVert\alpha x-\alpha y\rVert = 1$

However, by metric and norm properties,

$$\lVert\alpha x-\alpha y\rVert =\lVert\alpha(x-y)\rVert = \lvert\alpha\rvert\,\lVert x-y\rVert\le\vert \alpha \vert.1=\alpha,$$ a contradiction!!

Comment: You should make it clear by assuming that $\alpha \neq 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a normed field $K$ and that $X$ is a normed space over $K$.

The question has positive answer (i.e. discrete topology is not induced by any norm) if we implicitely assume that the normed field has a non-trivial norm. But if we further investigate into pathological cases, we can in fact find a normed space in which a trivial norm makes sense. So we have a counterexample.

Say $K$ is a finite field, then it can be shown that the only norm for $K$ is the trivial one. Now if we take the $K$-vector space $X = K^n$, then by fixing a basis (say, the canonical basis), there is a canonical way to define a norm over $X$, namely
$$
 |(x_1, \dots, x_n)| := \max_{i = 1, \dots, n} |x_i|,
$$
and it turns out to be a trivial norm over $X$. So the induced topology is the discrete topology.

So, to be fair, we can say that the trivial topology is not induced by any norm if we assume that $K$ has a non-trivial topology (the argument is the same given by Brian M. Scott and by user38268).