# Which is the difference between a topological space and a euclidean space? Is the topological space a generalization of a euclidean space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

My question arises from a paper in the AMM (Rauch, 1978) in which the illumination problem is treated. The problem is given in an euclidean space, however Rauch uses terms that I think are from the topological figures —$\partial S$: Boundary?, $\bar{S}$: Closure?, etc— I don't sure about the definitions.

Sorry for the English mistakes
Thank you!

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554698/example-of-a-vector-space-that-is-not-a-topological-space

Comment: Those are topological terms. I suggest you look into an introductory textbook on general topology, preferably one which does $not$ begin with metric spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Euclidean $n$-space is (most commonly) the space $\Bbb{R}^n$, with the dot product giving an inner product. This makes Euclidean $n$-space into an inner product space, which means it is a normed vector space, hence has a topological structure. In summary, a topological space is a *huge* generalisation of a Euclidean space, and all the notions from topology apply.