# Some Questions on Topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am having really hard time in my Functional Analysis II class. I never had this problem with Functional Analysis I class, which mostly focused on metrics spaces, normed spaces, banach space and hilbert space. In this class, we are mostly focused on topological vector space. I just find this space so confusing and hard to understand. I have some questions which I think will help me understand what is going on

Suppose that $X$ is a topological vector space (T.V.S) over field $F$

1. Does this mean that If $x,y\in X$, then $x+y\in X$ (linear space) and If $A,B\subseteq  X$, then $A\cup B\subseteq X$ (topology)?
2. Why is it mentioned in some textbooks that the topology over $F$ is euclidean topology? is this the only topology we can have?
3. Does it mean that $F$ can only have euclidean topology while $X$ can have it is own separate and different topology?
4. Does T.V.S have to be Hausdorff? If no, then why is Hausdorff used in most theorems in our lecture notes? What is different about a non-Hausdorff T.V.S?
5. Does T.V.S imply that addition and multiplication operators are continuous or is it a necessary condition?
6. Why is a linear space with a discrete topology is not a topological linear space?

Sorry if these questions look trivial, but they are just not clear to me.

Comment: All these question are solved just by looking at a definition of topological vector space, except perhaps for Hausdorffness. So, do you know a definition of topological vector space? What are you studying on?

Comment: 1. and 5. can be answered by looking at a definition indeed. For 2., "euclidean topology" only makes sense when $F$ is a field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, but even then, there are other interesting topologies on those fields as well, so no, it's not the only one. 3. see 2. 4. Depends on convention. Some sources exclude non-Hausdorff TVSs, because the only such ones come with the indiscrete topology, which is not very interesting. 6. Your assertion is not true in general.

Comment: 2. The base field $F$ is either $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ and always the usual Euclidean topology is considered there. For 1. and the other dots, please cite here the definition of a topological vector space that is being used. (E.g. most of the times Hausdorffness is included in the definition, but it seems not in your class.)

Comment: 5 is just part of the **definition** of what a TVS is. So necessary. If $V$ is a TVS over $F$ you **know** that scalar multiplication, addition and inverse ($x \to -x$) are continuous.

Comment: 4 is for convenience. If we ask for $V$ to be even $T_0$ it will also be Hausdorff. And all TVS's in practice are. It makes proofs easier.

Comment: The only requirement on the topology on $F$ is that we have a topological field. So **all** field operations are continuous. As in all of maths we give $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ their standard topologies, in which they are topological fields.

Comment: There are very good reasons **not to require Hausdorffness**: Spaces $\mathscr L^p$ of $p$-integrable functions are very natural examples but much more importantly, the category of Hausdorff TVS is very different from the category of all TVS. For example, the epimorphims in the former are the continuous linear maps with dense range and only in the latter they are surjective. This is crucial for many applications (i.e., solvability of a pde) where functional analysis is only a tool to solve "algebraic" problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers with references to this forum:

1.- Always is true that if $X$ is a topological vector space and $x,y\in X$ then $x+y\in X$ because $X$ is a vector space and the sum of vectors in a vector space is closed. The another condition ($A,B\subseteq X$ then $A\cup B\subseteq X$) is confusing because that property holds always by the definition of union. Maybe you refering to the topological structure?

2.- Not in general but the euclidean topology over the field $F$ ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is the most common topology. If your text doesn't say with topology is equiped in $F$, then sure is the euclidean topology.

3.- Yes. $X$ and $F$ are not related in topology. The topology in $X$ can be different from the topology in $F$.

4.- Not in general. If we have $X$ a vector space and consider the indiscrete topology over $X$, then $X$ is not Hausdorff and the sum and product are continuous, i.e., $X$ is a topological vector space.

5.- Is a necessary condition. The definition of a topological vector space is "$X$ is a topological vector space if $X$ is a vector space and the operations of sum and dot product are continuous with the topology of $X$".

6.- Here is a good reference for your question: [Topological vector space with discrete topology is the zero space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492483/topological-vector-space-with-discrete-topology-is-the-zero-space)

Comment: Do you mean in a topological vector space there are two topologies, one on $X$ and one on $F$?

Comment: @gbd $X$ and $F$ are distinct sets.

Comment: @arnett, but does $F$ must have a topology to be a topological vector space? Or just $X$ must have a topology?

Comment: @gbd $F$ must also have a topology, and this is usually assumed to be the Euclidean one when $F$ are the real or complex numbers.

Comment: @gbd Scalar multiplication $F\times X\rightarrow X$ also has to be continuous, and $F$ must have a topology for that requirement to even make sense.

Comment: @BrianO, Does this mean that the topology on $X$ is used to make the addition continuous, while the topology on $F$ is used to make the multiplication continuous?

Comment: @gbd no it's the combination of both that matters. If we would give the field $F$ the discrete topology (which is a valid topological field) then scalar multiplication wouldn't be continuous over $\Bbb R^n$ (in the Euclidean topology) any more.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, what if we give $X$ the discrete topology and $F$ the euclidean topology?

Comment: @gbd Also no TVS.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, in this case, which operation would not be continuous:  addition or multiplication?

Comment: @gbd scalar multiplication of course. Addition and inverse are continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, so addition is always continuous no matter what topologies $X$ and $F$ have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134471/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-gbd).