# The discrete metric on $\mathbb R $ is not induced by a norm

Tags: real-analysis

Show that discrete metric on $\mathbb R$  *i.e*

$d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ cannot be derived from a norm.

Comment: Same question than for your previous post... What have you tried? What are the axioms of a norm?

Comment: This metric is not homogeneous.

Comment: What would happen if you helped? if you can not help ,Do not answer unnecessarily.

Comment: You should post your effort on a problem, when you ask questions in the future. Also, please use mathjax and proper titles when prasing questions.

Comment: you right.I agree but first i have tried and I just started using this site

Comment: First, you have to understand that if you have a norm $|| \cdot ||$, then how do you get a metric/distance function from it?  Well, you subtract two elements!

So the distance between elements $a$ and $b$ under the metric induced by the norm $|| \cdot ||$ is defined as $||a - b||$.  

You should verify that the function $d(a,b) := ||a - b||$ is actually a metric. 

Now that you understand how a norm induces/gives rise to a metric, you have to show that the metric $d(x,y) := \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq y \\ 0 & x = y \end{cases}$ is **not** induced by a norm.

Comment: (cont.) Suppose that it were induced by a norm $|| \cdot ||$.  Then we know $d(x,y) = ||x - y||$.  But we also have $d(x,y) =1$ if $x \neq y$, and $0$ if $x = y$.

Well, if $x = y$, $||x - y|| = 0$ by properties of a norm, so there's no problem there.  But what if $x \neq y$?  Then does $||x - y|| = 1$ always?  No because we know that a norm satisfies for any real number $c$, $||u|| = |c| \cdot||u||$.  

So, take for example, $c = 2$.  Then if $x \neq y$, we have $2x \neq 2y$, right?

Comment: (cont.) But then $d(x,y) = 1$ and $d(2x,2y) = 1$.  But if $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$, then we have $||x-y|| = 1$ and $||2x - 2y|| = 1$.  But this means $||x - y|| = ||2x - 2y||$.  But we can pull the $2$ out on the right hand side, giving $||x - y|| = 2||x - y||$.  Dividing both sides by $||x-y||$ (which is nonzero since $x \neq y$ by assumption) gives $1 = 2$, which is a contradiction!  Thus, the metric $d$ is *not* induced by a norm.

Comment: Sorry, in my second to last comment, I wrote $||u|| = |c| \cdot ||u||$, but I should have written $||cu|| = |c| \cdot ||u||$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200023

Answer (score 4):

Suppose it is possible, the norm of $1$ would have to be $1$ because $d(0,1)=1$ but then the norm of $2$ would have to be $2$ (since  $||av||$ is equal to $|a|\cdot||v||$). This implies $d(0,2)=2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $d$ is induced by a norm, which we will denote $||\cdot||$

Then $||x|| = d(x,0)$.

Note that: $||2\times 1|| = d(2,0) = 1\neq 2 =  2\times ||1||$